# Wordpress - run function at a specific time of a day

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have tried this solution but I can't get it to work:

[Run function at specific time](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126315/run-function-at-specific-time)

Here is my example:

```
//this is for testing purposes
function my_cron_schedules($schedules){
if(!isset($schedules["1min"])){
    $schedules["1min"] = array(
        'interval' => 60,
        'display' => __('Once a minute'));
}

return $schedules;
}
add_filter('cron_schedules','my_cron_schedules');

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_scheduled_event' ) ) { wp_schedule_event( 
strtotime( '2019-01-04 19:39:00' ), '1min', 'my_scheduled_event' ); }

add_action( 'my_scheduled_event', 'update_ratings' );

function update_ratings() { 
//do some stuff..
}
```

Comment: For the record, the answer you linked states "Further, it needs to be understood that wp_cron is triggered by page loads so if your site hasn't got huge amounts of traffic, then the function won't fire precisely at the time defined. There are workarounds for this though." In other words, this isn't actually triggered by cron itself, but by loading the associated page(s). This will not run unless someone visits the page(s) after the schedule interval has passed.

Comment: If you want to have a guaranteed, scheduled event to be fired every minute, you're going to have to actually enable cron itself on the server and edit the crontab. PHP absolutely _cannot_ handle this on its own. Any purely PHP-based solution will require manually running the PHP script. Your current solution requires periodic web traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tested it, but it doesn't working. 
The 1 minute schedule is only for testing purposes. My initial plan is to schedule it once per day at a specific time.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the interval is 1 minute or 1 day. The problem is that even if you have the code scheduled correctly, it's not going to run unless someone manually triggers the script to run. Someone needs to visit the page at the exact time you want the script to run if you want it to run at that time. You cannot get around that. That's a built-in limitation. The only way around it is to edit the server's `crontab`.

Comment: Either a human being needs to trigger the script or a machine does. If you want, you can set up a cron job on a different machine designed to visit the specific page at the schedule time. That would work. But you can't get this to run purely on its own with only PHP.

Comment: I understand your point. It does not have to be at the exact time. But the problem is that this is not working on my side at all.

Comment: In that case, you have some debugging to do. Unfortunately I'm not particularly familiar with WordPress itself, but try moving the `add_action()` call to the top. It's possible that the order of operations is important here.

Comment: Another possible point of error to consider is possible timezone issues. What is the timezone being used for `strtotime()`? Compare the time in that timezone to what it would be in your timezone. If the time is defined in a timezone that's later than your own, it could be that your own timezone hasn't crossed the time threshold required for the script to start running.

Comment: Minor correction: The problem would be if the time is being set for a timezone _earlier_ than yours, not later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in scheduled cron jobs. While testing I had previously set cron job for the same hook. After inspecting cron jobs I managed to delete that test schedule and now it is working.